# Getting URL content sometimes contains strange values

Tags: java

I have use this function to get the content of a URL as String:

```
static String getUrlContent(String site) {
    String text = "";
    try {
        URL url = new URL(site);
        HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        con.addRequestProperty("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Widows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:57.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/57.0");
        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(con.getInputStream());
        while(true) {
            byte[] s = new byte[1000];
            if(in.read(s) == -1) break;
            text += new String(s);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
    return text;
}
```

Sometimes this string contains large sequences of strange characters that Eclipse only displays as squares. If I call it with same URL again they disappear (or appear at another position). Why is that and how can I avoid it?

Comment: what is you return content?

Comment: Can you please share the string value which displays squares? I have a feeling you might need to validate the string with ASCII or non-ASCII characters.

Comment: no i can't these characters don't get copied. When i write it to a file and open it in notepad++ they are schown as NUL with a black background. Btw, i just noted that there are always 631 one of them in a sequence